# Table View help in Swift - DetailedView

Tags: iphone, swift

how can I customize the DeatiledView of a table View in swift based on what cell the user clicks on? I already have the new class set up with text, but not sure how to make the if statement that customizes the text for each cell clicked. Please let me know if you can help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html), particularly "Configuring the Destination Controller When a Segue is Triggered" in section "Coordinating Efforts Between View Controllers".

It is a very basic question - not really suitable for this platform. You should at least read the documentation.

Comment: You should click the check mark above and come back when you have a more concrete problem with your code.